# control flow graph of a c program to find worst possible path

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, static-analysis, control-flow-graph

Are there any tools, libraries, or frameworks to get the control flow graph of a C program, and find the worst possible path a program can take?

When I read the other questions related to control flow graphs, I came across a few tools which can generate the control flow graph. Is there any way to use them to find the worst possible path?

Comment: as i hav already accepted an answer, let me add a note, Understand 2 by [link](http://scitools.com)  and its c, perl , python api's help getting a cgf very easy,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the graph will ever have loops in it, then no -- there isn't a foolproof way to figure this, as the question is equivalent to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_Problem).  Short version:  it's impossible for a program, given an arbitrary other program, to even determine whether it will ever return.  You could possibly determine *potential* infinite loops, but the only way to be anywhere near certain is to actually run the program with an exhaustive set of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be in interested in [Worst Case Execution Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worst-case_execution_time) which, if succesful, in some sense must have found your worst control flow path.

Regarding libaries for computing C control flow graphs, see our [flow analysis support for DMS](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/FlowAnalysis.html) for C and other languages,